# Safe.create is not a function - gnosis safe-core-sdk

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am trying to follow the example from here, mostly to add transaction / sign off-chain: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md

but i got the error: TypeError: Safe.create is not a function

```
import EthersAdapter from "@gnosis.pm/safe-ethers-lib";
import Safe, { SafeFactory } from "@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import abi from "./abi/abi.js";

const bulkMint = async () => {
    const infuraProvider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider("rinkeby", {
        projectId: "..",
        projectSecret: "...",
    });

    const privateKey = "...";
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
        `...`,
        infuraProvider
    );
    const signer = await wallet.connect(infuraProvider);
    const safeAddress = "...";
    const contractAddress = "...";
    let ethAdapterOwner1 = new EthersAdapter({ ethers, signer });

    // error here
    const safeSdk = await Safe.create({
        ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner1,
        safeAddress: GNOSIS_SAFE_ADDR,
    });
    // rest of irrelevant code
 
};
```

I am using these:
@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk: "^2.0.0",
@gnosis.pm/safe-ethers-lib: "^1.0.0",
@node 16.13

May I know if I am missing anything.

Here is the log for Safe object (console.log(Safe))

```
{
  ContractManager: [class ContractManager],
  SafeFactory: [class SafeFactory],
  EthSignSignature: [class EthSignSignature],
  standardizeSafeTransactionData: [Getter],
  default: [class Safe]
}
```

Comment: Hmm that should work. The method is defined here https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/safe-core-sdk/src/Safe.ts#L83. Can you log the Safe object? (e.g. `console.log(Safe)`)

Comment: hi @Richard,

This is the log for safe object:


`{
  ContractManager: [class ContractManager],
  SafeFactory: [class SafeFactory],
  EthSignSignature: [class EthSignSignature],
  standardizeSafeTransactionData: [Getter],
  default: [class Safe]
}`

Comment: you need to destructure the `default` property

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the latest safe versions:

"@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^0.1.1",
"@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^1.10.1",

I realized that the Safe object contains a default property which points to the Safe class. I used the ugly trick:

await Safe.default.create(...) which works in js. In ts a bit of type tweaking would be needed