# TypeError: Safe.create is not a function

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature

I want to get the already deployed contracts in safe

```
  const safeSdk:Safe = await Safe.create({
    ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner1,
    safeAddress: "0x31cbf07d16F51Ad83C2c4ab90579DE863da5A9b7",
  });
```

Comment: you may check the answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123067/safe-create-is-not-a-function-gnosis-safe-core-sdk) if it could be helpful.